# How to show specific meta keys of all posts in admin panel?

Tags: post-meta, meta-query, admin-menu

I have some common meta keys on every post.

Ex: hotel_person, hotel_number
All the posts have these two meta keys.

I want to show these meta key values and the post titles. All these values and post title should be able to shown in admin panel. (All the posts are hotels. no need to consider the category)

Eg:
If I have two hotels in my site, i want show like below in my admin panel.

```
Hotel 1
hotel_person1
hotel_number1

-----------------

Hotel 2
hotel_person2
hotel_number2
```

I tried something but it's not working.

**[APPENDED - What I've tried]**
first I added an admin menu.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'hotel_contact' );
function hotel_contact(){
    add_menu_page( 'Hotel Contact', 'Hotel Contact', 'manage_options', 'hotel_contacts', 'hotel_contact_function', plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ), 7 ); 
}
```

Then I created the function to get the `hotel contact` number

```
function hotel_contact_function() {         
    echo get_post_meta( 3, 'hotel_contact_number' , true ); 
}
```

It gives me 3rd hotels(post ID) contact number when I visit to the admin menu `Hotel Contact`
Then I've tried to get all post meta data for the meta key `hotel_contact_number`. So I've changed the function `hotel_contact_function` to:

```
function hotel_contact_function() {         
    $contacts = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hotel_contact_number' , true ); 
        foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
            echo $contact.'<br/>';
            }
    }
```

But it gives a warning when I visit to the admin menu `Hotel contact` : `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/cyberact/public_html/mysite.com/wp-content/themes/u-design-child/functions.php on line 601`

Comment: What did you try so far?  We can work through it.

Comment: @AndrewBartel Please have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: If you want to do foreach, your $contacts should return an array. Now it is returning a string. Change your 3rd argument to false. You should do print_r( $contact ) instead of echo as well to show available values.

Comment: @SLH thank you for that. I changed the code to : `function hotel_contact_function() {   
 //echo get_post_meta( 213, 'hotel_contact_number' , true ); 
 $contacts = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hotel_contact_number' , false ); 
  foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
   print_r ($contact).'<br/>';
   }
 }` but still the same warning message I am getting.